# Close tabs from Tabcontrol but keep One tab Active in the end

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am workin on tab Controls in WPF. I have added a set of tabs in my tab control and also implemented Close button method which works fine.

```
private void CloseTab(object source, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {            
        TabItem tabItem = args.Source as TabItem; 

        if (tabItem != null)
        {
            TabControl tabControl = tabItem.Parent as TabControl;
            if (tabControl != null)
                tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);             

        }            
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="ConnectTab" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}">
                        <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Connect" > 
                        </tablocal:CloseableTabItem>
                        <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="I2C" />
                        <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Voltage" />
                        <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Clock" />
```

The problem i am facing is to keep one tab active(shouldnt close) after all the tabs have been closed. Basically the last tab left in tabcontrol shud not close even if user clicks the X button on tab.

Comment: Are you missing a statement for reloading the form? WPF and Silverlight need a "Refresh" action to update the forms.

Comment: I am able to close the 4 tabs which i added as seen above. But I want atleast one tab to remain active in the end. It shud not close

Comment: I suggest to you to set the visibility of the x button in the remaining tabitem to collapsed.

Comment: If you were to use a Command rather than a click event then you can modify the commands CanExecute property to false (and notify via PropertyChanged) when there's only one left and the close button UI should automatically become disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition to -

```
if (tabControl != null && tabControl.Items.Count > 1)
    tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);
```

Comment: But, if you have 3 tabs, T0,T1,T2 and you do clic in T2, it will close!

Comment: ^ yeah you are right. basically I wanted any final tab to remain active even if user removes any n-1 tabs. And the above answer by Makubex does that :)